# HTTP POST request for JSON in Perl

Tags: json, perl, httprequest, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to configure the wireless settings (like setting ssid as "vinoth" channel as "1") in Linksys EA4500 AP. I could see the below POST message using wireshark.

```
3E@@!dPzY+2K
SPOST /JNAP/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-JNAP-Action: http:cisco.com/jnap/core/Transaction
X-JNAP-Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http:/cisco.com/     <<<<==== routerip
Content-Length: 474
Cookie: initial-tab=; ui-proxy-path=local; admin-auth=Basic%20YWRtaW46YWRtaW4%3D; current-applet=7B1F462B-1A78-4AF6-8FBB-0C221703BEA4
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

[{"action":"http:/cisco.com/jnap/wirelessap/SetRadioSettings","request":{"radios":[{"radioID":"RADIO_2.4GHz","settings":{"isEnabled":true,"mode":"802.11bgn","ssid":"vinoth","broadcastSSID":true,"channelWidth":"Auto","channel":1,"security":"None"}}]}},{"action":"http://cisco.com/jnap/guestnetwork/SetGuestNetworkSettings","request":{"isGuestNetworkEnabled":false,"guestSSID":"vinoth-guest","guestPassword":"BeMyGuest","maxSimultaneousGuests":5,"broadcastGuestSSID":false}}]
```

I tried automating the above action using Perl but it didn't workout. As I am new to this JSON page I don't know how exactly the POST message to be sent.

content I kept for $json is

```
'{"action":"http:/cisco.com/jnap/wirelessap/SetRadioSettings",' .
        '"request":{"radios":{"radioID":"RADIO_2.4GHz","settings":'.'{"isEnabled":true,"mode":"802.11bgn","ssid":"vinoth212","broadcastSSID":true,"channelWidth":"Auto","channel":1,"security":"None"}}}},{"action":"http://cisco.com/jnap/guestnetwork/SetGuestNetworkSettings",' .
    '"request":{"isGuestNetworkEnabled":false,"guestSSID":"vinoth-guest","guestPassword":"BeMyGuest","maxSimultaneousGuests":5,"broadcastGuestSSID":false}}';
```

and the code:

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use LWP;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $ip = $self->{ip};
    my $url = "http://$ip/";
    my $json = "";

    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST=>$url);
    $req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');
    $req->authorization_basic("admin", "admin");
    $req->content($json);
```

Below code for checking the request status

```
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ($res->is_success) {
    my $message = $res->decoded_content;
    print "received the message";
    } else {
    print "HTTP get code: ", $res->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP get: msg: ", $res->message, "\n";
    }
```

Please help me in fixing this. Awaiting for your valuable reply.

P.S: In the Wireshark Post message the links are not proper as I am unable to post the query with more than 2 links.

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: I tried to post my code in my question but it said lot of indendation constraints so I removed it.

Comment: May be it's Referer header? You don't have it in your code...

Comment: what should be the referer header? I see two links on that action message. Could you tell me how to parse it??

Comment: `Referer: http:/cisco.com/     <<<<==== routerip` Same you have in Wireshark log

Comment: I tried this. my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST=>"http://192.168.1.1/"); $req->header(content-type=>"application/json";$req->content($json); my $res = $ua->request($req); and the result of $res->is_success returned "Internal Server Error" and error code "500"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code `$req->authorization_basic("admin", "admin");` it means `Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` HTTP header when make any request.

But From your wireshirk's header it is `X-JNAP-Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`, which is different thing(a custom header). So remove that `authorization_basic` from your block and use these ones:

```
$req->header('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$req->header('X-JNAP-Action' => 'http:cisco.com/jnap/core/Transaction');
$req->header('X-JNAP-Authorization' => 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=');
## YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= is base64 of admin:admin
$req->header('X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Comment: I tried the above but still it didn't work. Post message from Wireshark (tried login page) : POST /JNAP HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Host: 192.168.1.1
Referer: http://192.168.1.1/ui/dynamic/login.html
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.03
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-JNAP-Action: http://cisco.com/jnap/core/CheckAdminPassword
X-JNAP-Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: "HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required\nConnection: close\nDate: Tue, 14 Aug 2012 22:52:13 GMT\nServer: lighttpd/1.4.28\nContent-Length: 357\nContent-Type: text/html\nClient-Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 03:51:30 GMT\nClient-Peer: 192.168.1.1:80\nClient-Response-Num: 1\nTitle: 411 - Length Required\n\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>\n<//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\n\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\<head>\n  <title>411 - Length Required</title>\n </head>\n <body>\n  <h1>411 - Length Required</h1>\n </body>\n</html>\n"

Comment: I now fixed the content-length error. But getting "301 Moved Permanently" error. "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\nDate: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 00:03:42 GMT\nLocation: http://192.168.1.1/JNAP/\nServer: lighttpd/1.4.28\nContent-Length: 0\nClient-Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 05:02:59 GMT\nClient-Peer: 192.168.1.1:80\nClient-Response-Num: 1\n\n"
HTTP get code: 301
HTTP get msg : Moved Permanently

Comment: Got it finally. I missed a "/" in the url. I gave "http://192.168.1.1/JNAP" instead of "http://192.168.1.1/JNAP/".

Comment: Sounds great!! I was off for few hours so couldn't reply. FYI, to handle redirect you can use `$ua->max_redirect(2)` from `LWP::UserAgent`

Comment: In GET method, how to get the contents of a page? I am getting either the JS or the html page but it doesn't have the values I look for (like SSID, Radio ID, Channel etc...). Could u help? Even in Wireshark, I can see those values only when I use "Follow TCP Stream" option.

Comment: The thing you are doing using `$res->decoded_content` is alright. I am guessing the problem can be the html source may have `iframe` or `ajax` that's why those fields are not on there.

Comment: so how to get those values using HTTP GET?

Comment: You have to TAP those request, or debug html/javascript for the links. Its more like scraping then coding.

Comment: Gotcha! When I tried with GET requests, the webpage returned with either CSS or JS so I had no clue how to get the values I expect. Later tried with POST - constructed a POST header which I got through "Follow TCP Stream" and I got the values which I expected.